# Using Windows cmd as the visual studio dev cmd

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2015, cmd, customization

I'm currently learning C/C++ programming in university. We have been using the visual studio developer cmd to compile all our code.
Recently, I learned I could set custom paths for the CMD, and have been able to use GHCi, for example, straight from the command prompt, just by typing `ghci`.

I want to be able to use the commands from the VS Dev cmd in the windows cmd (or in a similar way to `ghci`) , since I have it pinned to my taskbar and have customized the colour, font and transparency. (What can I say, I'm picky about looks, and the VS Dev cmd resets these settings every time I open it).

I have already tried various things, the first was adding all the dev cmd paths to the normal cmd. I even set a couple INCLUDE and LIB paths (Although maybe not the right ones, since when I tried running the `cl` command it gives me the following error:

> "fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no include path set", or it can't find stdio.h)

Here's some links to other things I've tried (With my result in brackets):

- [Configuring cl CMD compiling Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959191/configuring-cl-cmd-compiling-windows) (Comes up with "ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder." when run, doesn't keep my colour settings anyway)
- https://remyblok.tweakblogs.net/blog/10985/start-all-command-prompts-as-visual-studio-developer-command-prompt (The cmd just says it can't find specified path, maybe I'm not putting the right thing in the regestry?)
- https://www.codeproject.com/questions/706617/how-to-open-visual-studio-command-prompt-using-win (This one had 5 solutions, but most seemed to be about making a shortcut to the dev cmd, not what I want, couldn't find where it said to go in the first solution either)

Basically, I want one cmd (with my custom colour/font/transparency, VS Dev cmd doesn't seem to do this) for all the things I do, but being able to compile c files with the cl command doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated, if this is even possible. If it can't happen, or if you want any clarification in case I missed something you think might be important in answering, or if I'm ill-informed and stupid, just tell me straight.

(Also this is my first time using this site so I hope this isn't breaking and guidelines/rules, I've tried to make it concise)

EDIT:

This has been answered in how to get the VS Dev Prompt keeping most of my custom settings, which I can work with. But feel free to answer if you have information about the original setting the windows cmd to automatically set the environment to work with the VS compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Developer Command Prompt?

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio    14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.  Where would I put that? I tried in the environment variables > ComSpec, but I still get the error "no include path set". if you're asking why I don't use the Developer command prompt that is in the VS tools, it's because it goes back to the default cmd settings for colour and font, and I'd rather have it stay with my settings. Do you know if it's possible to change the Dev cmd colours and fonts so that they stay even when I exit?

Comment: Not sure,  You could edit the bat file and set the colors in there.

Comment: I now realise you probably meant put that in the console, because that worked and allowed me to use cl, however when I exited the cmd and relaunched it, I need to put it in again. is there a way so I can make that happen automatically?

Comment: OK, Thanks, I'll try to do that.

Comment: Apparently the transparency actually does stay when I exit, as does the font. the colour I set in the bat file works though. Thanks for answering and giving me the solution of typing in a bat file. I feel quite stupid now since I never even thought of that haha